# Qt Download confusion

Tags: android, qt, installation

This is a very simple question, but I don't see through it with the information I gathered so far. I want to download Qt (as I have done on other machines before), but since I'm planning to deploy to Android as well, I ask myself, if I should download the "**Qt 5.8.0 for Android (Windows 32-bit, 1.3 GB)**" binary right away instead of "**Qt 5.8.0 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 5.3.0, 1.2 GB)**" and then getting the Android SDK etc.
I don't really know what the former really is/includes... is it the Qt package already including the Android SDK? If so, which compiler/bit version is included in the package... This is quite simple, but I can't really figure it out.

Comment: If you want to deploy to android and windows, you have to download both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt for Android includes the code and binaries needed (but not sufficient) to target Android. You *also* need the Android SDK. It does *not* include anything related to targeting Windows, and does not include any Android build tools other than the tools Qt provides by itself (qmake, uic, qrc, etc.). It comes with Qt Creator.

Qt for Windows MinGW includes the code, binaries, compiler and libraries needed to target Windows. It has nothing to do with Android at all. It is a self-contained development environment and includes Qt Creator.

If you want to target *both* Android and Windows, you'll need *both* downloads.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure about that, because the files are equally large...why is that? Will there be any redundancies, which I can circumvent?

Comment: Oh... I didn't assume that they were entirely independent... Every single part of the Qt library is different for "Qt for Android"?

Comment: The only common parts are the include files, some build scaffolding and helper tools, and documentation. The meat of it - all the target-specific binaries - are completely different as they are for a different architecture and configuration, after all. Recall that you've downloaded *binaries*. If you wanted to download Qt sources only and then build for Windows and for Android, you can also do that - the build folders will be much bigger than what you downloaded, though. For Qt, you should conservatively allocate about 10GB per a combined debug+release build with release symbols.

Comment: Okay thank you for your input. I'm just baffled, because the "Qt for Windows" enables to deploy for Windows, Mac etc and the same file size (download) is needed for deploying for Android ("Qt for Android"). Or am I misunderstand here a lot more than I thought? I'm talking about the offline installers on the qt download page. I thought, with "for host" was meant the developing platform, not the target platform... (Thanks for your time! Please help me to clarify this, I'll of course accept your answer.)

Comment: Plus, for instance, adding the Android x86 option in the Qt Online Installer only adds another 200MB to the size... (in contrast to "Qt for Android")?

Comment: The online installer can download everything and will share the headers, build architecture, Qt Creator, etc. I was talking about platform-specific downloads. If you do the "universal" download - all online installers are "universal" - then you should select the options you want and you're set.

Comment: Ahhhhhh, that sounds a lot more like what I thought! "**Qt for X**" is the whole Qt packet for deploying to (or _running_ on??) **X**, which is why they are both so large (and about equal in size). With the online installer, I can avoid redundancies, if I got you correctly. If you'd put that into your answer, I'd be really glad. :) I'll accept it already, though.